# Are the R.xxx.xxx resource id's static through versions?

Tags: android, persistence

If I were to store a string resource id in a database, could I expect the resource id to still point me to the desired string when I pull it back a few versions down the line?

Sample Case:

- Store the recource Id `0x7f060003`, with the assumption it points
  to the string **"I'm a pleasant string!"** for an inderterminate
  amount of time.
- Time comes along in which I need the resource, but X versions have passed, will the resource id still point to **"I'm a pleasant string!"**?

Comment: If your hardcoding a String resource ID in the DB why not just save the String there? One duplicated string will reduce the complexity 10 fold of the answer outlined below.

Comment: That's probably the wiser idea. Call me a glutton for punishment ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you say X versions have passed, do you mean you have changed your source code? And updated the apk?

The R id integers are created at compile time. Therefore constant in your app once built.

However if you add a new layout / id / drawable your ID's *will* change.

Comment: Yes, I meant that the source code has been modified or revised X times up to and including resource modification. Is there a way to modify aapt to prevent resource id changes?

Comment: I don't know about that BUT a dirty hack could be to name your resoruce you don't want to change aaaa_your_res_name. Therefore it will *technically* always be compiled first and have the same res id. **BUT** I would **not** rely on this method and test it heavily.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend to rely on this fact at all. This part of build process can be changed at any time. You're a better of using String identifiers as other answer pointed out (even though they are less effective then simple int ids).

Comment: @inazaruk, Oh by no means am I relying on this. Blundell had already answered my question, I was just curious about a hack or work around. It is way to unstable to actually do for anything other than curiosity.

Answer (score 20):

Use getResources().getIdentifier() instead. This way you can retrieve your ressource by its name, even if its id changes. Here's an example:

```
int resID = getResources().getIdentifier("nameofthedrawable", "drawable", "com.your.project");
```

You can then save just the name of the ressource in the database, and retrieve the ressources later from the database.

See this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) for more info.

Comment: +1 for this solving suggesstion :) Please note that this code also has several disadvantages. You may not change the drawable's name later without changing it at code too. It's kinda likely to oversee this, I think. If you would forget this, a lot of very-very-hard-to-debug errors will occur!

Comment: Does anyone know how does using this method over R.id.xxx affect performance?

Comment: From the docs for this method: `Note: use of this function is discouraged.  It is much more efficient to retrieve resources by identifier than by name.`

Answer (score 1):

You can fix resource ids by creating a public.xml in the res/values directory.
Here is one I have used:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <public type="drawable" name="button" id="0x7f020000" />
    <public type="drawable" name="button_flat" id="0x7f020001" />
    <public type="drawable" name="button_flat_square" id="0x7f020002" />
    <public type="drawable" name="button_flat_vert" id="0x7f020003" />
    <public type="drawable" name="button_grey" id="0x7f020004" />
    <public type="drawable" name="right" id="0x7f020005" />
    <public type="drawable" name="left" id="0x7f020006" />
    <public type="drawable" name="up" id="0x7f020007" />
    <public type="drawable" name="down" id="0x7f020008" />
    <public type="drawable" name="red" id="0x7f020009" />
    <public type="drawable" name="green" id="0x7f02000A" />
    <public type="drawable" name="yellow" id="0x7f02000B" />
    <public type="drawable" name="blue" id="0x7f02000C" />
    <public type="drawable" name="plus" id="0x7f020010" />
    <public type="drawable" name="minus" id="0x7f020011" />
</resources>
```

Comment: This method no longer works since release of gradle 1.3.0 back in 2015. Here is the link to corresponding issue: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=182046

Answer (score -1):

The best solution would be to create a map of your icons in your code

```
val iconMap: HashMap<String, Int>
```

String is your key (to that drawable resource) that you can keep in your database, or even the key from backend API response

Int is the resource drawable

```
iconMap.put("cat", R.drawable.ic_cat)
iconMap.getOrDefault("dog", R.drawable.empty)
```